# How to host a project built with adapter-static and dynamic routes?

Tags: sveltekit

I have a Sveltekit project with a similar structure

```
src/
├ routes/
│ ├ [...unknown]
│ │ └ +page.svelte
│ ├ category/
│ │ ├ [...path]/
│ │ │ └ +page.svelte
│ │ └ +page.svelte
│ └ normal/
│   └ +page.svelte
```

With the following config

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        prerender: {
            entries: [
                '*',
                '/[...unknown]',
                '/category/[...path]',
            ]
        },
    },
};

export default config;
```

the project can be built without errors and in `preview` mode the routing works as expected.

After deploying it to firebase hosting the dynamic routes give a `Page not found` error described in this question [Sveltekit [...slug] dynamic routing returns 404 error after deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73531099/sveltekit-slug-dynamic-routing-returns-404-error-after-deployment) Trying the provided solution the error on the page changes to `Dynamic Link Not Found`

So besides hoping to solve this, I'm first of all interested in understanding what exactly is going on here with the dynamic routes and what server and setup is needed to host the project where these routes/files will be correctly resolved

```
/[...unknown].html
/category/[...path].html
```

Comment: The concept of having a static site and dynamic routes does not make much sense to me. If the server really is only serving files, it should not be possible to map an infinite number of possible routes ot a finite number of files.

Comment: @H.B. Not sure I get your point... what's your suggestion to do instead?

Comment: Well, it depends. maybe this can be made to work as is, if Firebase can do more than just serve files. If you had access to a Node server, dynamic routing should not be an issue (using `@sveltejs/adapter-node`), which again depends on the platform you host on.

Comment: @H.B. what more than serving files has to be done exactly? Isn't this like a nested single page app where basically every route inside `/category` like `/category/sth` or `/category/sth/else` should be handled via `/category/[...path].html`? Looking at the generated files this is what I thought happened. *"map an infinite number of possible routes ot a finite number of files"* Isn't this how a SPA works? Static files served with a rewrite to `/` or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: That is how SPAs tend to work, yes, but this requires the special behavior of returning a response that does not correspond to the given path.  The default (and sometimes only) behavior of a file server is to turn the URL path into a file system path and return the respective file or possibly some fallback 404 error page (even that is not always possible).

Comment: @H.B. Serving a single page app is no problem with a `rewrite` config with firebase hosting. So should hosting this be possible as well because it's like I described that the nested routes need to be rewritten to the [...slug].html file that's 'in charge'?

Comment: You are then trying to recreate the original SvelteKit router semantics using this configuration. There is no guarantee that this is always going to work.

Comment: (I tried to build a site with a similar structure and it would not even output dynamic routes. It just generated the pages for categories, for which links existed somewhere e.g. in the root category page. Note that the adapter has options to enable a full SPA mode and there is an option to define a `fallback` page which could help with the dynamic routes.)

Comment: Thanks @H.B. The fallback page might indeed be what I'm missing for the dynamic routes... Will go through the static-adapter description again and test all the options